# Mobile Safari prevent body scroll when menu open

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

I have been fighting with this thing for several weeks now. I just can't figure it out.

I'm trying to prevent horizontal scrolling of the body when the menu is open. Here is a complete jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/vopeq/38/edit

Seems like any solution only undoes other things that are working the way I would like them to. So I added the requirements to the jsbin to keep track of which are satisfied with each version.

### UPDATE

Maybe it's too good to be true, but I think I have all requirements satisfied, but I still need to check on android devices:

http://jsbin.com/vopeq/61

The thing I learned, that was tripping me up for so long and I didn't realize it, is that `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` element, in Mobile Safari, doesn't do squat! I had to move my styles to prevent scrolling down one level of elements.

And [Ed4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357566/ed4) pointed me in the right direction. I needed to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent of the element I'm moving with `left: 85%` instead of the element itself (I was trying to do it all on the `<body>`).

So I have a `body > .container`, on which I do the `overflow: hidden` and `body > .container > .content`, which I push over using `position: relative` and `left: 85%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more of a design spec than a question, so rather than try to design the whole layout for you, I'll point out why your jsbin doesn't work.

Don't try to set `left` on `body`. If `body` is protruding offscreen, you're not going to be able to reliably stop scrolling.

Instead, keep `body` stationary with 100% width and height, so it can serve as your visible window boundary. When you want to lock the scrolling, you can set `overflow: hidden` on `body`. Handle the slide-over and scrolling menu with separate divs inside body.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the right combination of positioning on the right elements. Which elements would you position and how?

Comment: Another clue: `overflow: hidden` on `body` doesn't work properly in Mobile Safari ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/natosa/1)). But it does work properly on a div ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/natosa/2)).